# How to add error cache for interceptor at angular 5?

Tags: angular

I am new to angular. Interceptor created as service. Working fine. Now adding error catcher. When I add '.do' part it will not be working. If I removed this part working fine. As well cannot find the reason why this is not working. Shown my code below. Please tell me if I was anything handled wrong.
Thanks in advance.

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
 import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() { }
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (request.url.indexOf("UserLogin") > 0 || request.url.indexOf("GetLogo") > 0) {
      return next.handle(request);
    }
    var cookie = document.cookie;
    var token = cookie.split("authToken=")[1].split(";")[0];
    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    });
    return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {}, (err: any) => {
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        // do error handling here
      }
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: what's the result? what stop working?

Comment: It doesn't send any request to api if I was added '.do' part (no console error). Perhaps I removed it request send to api working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you are able to pipe that do on rxJS 5.5 (That one is compatible to Angular 5), try changing the line to

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {}, (err: any) => {
      console.log(err)
    }));
```

Let me know how you go.

[rxJS reference](https://blog.hackages.io/rxjs-5-5-piping-all-the-things-9d469d1b3f44)